# Глюк checkbox в Bootstrap

Tags: checkbox, bootstrap, css

Привожу пример.

http://jsfiddle.net/gw6xt8sr/

Внизу вставил три checkbox. И как можно видеть, они располагаются криво, а должны в ряд...

```
<div class="checkbox" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100px">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>      
    <div class="checkbox" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top:100px">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>      
    <div class="checkbox" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 100px">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: @sitev_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Позиционирование нужно задавать при необходимости не чекбоксам, а контейнеру, в котором они лежат, а чекбоксы bootstrap ставит сам, как нужно:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top:100px">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>      
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>      
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Посмотреть](http://jsfiddle.net/gw6xt8sr/1/)

**UPD.** 
Почитайте [документацию](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls) по этому вопросу, даже без знания английского можно взять код и использовать. Не нужно придумывать никаких велосипедов, их уже придумали.
[Пример с инлайновыми чекбоксами](http://jsfiddle.net/gw6xt8sr/3/).

Comment: спасибо, получилось... я немного переделал, мне нужно вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/g72wgav3/

Comment: @sitev_ru, обновил ответ, мне кажется, абсолютное позиционирование здесь не нужно совсем